# How do I escape special characters in user input for a SQL LIKE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, code-injection

Take the following example (SQL Server 2008 - might work with more). You'll have to imagine `@query` being some parameter whose source is user input:

```
DECLARE @query varchar(100)
SET @query = 'less than 1% fat'

CREATE TABLE X ([A] VARCHAR(100))
INSERT X VALUES ('less than 1% fat')
INSERT X VALUES ('less than 1% of doctors recommend this - it''s full of fat!')
SELECT * FROM X WHERE A LIKE '%' + @query + '%'
DROP TABLE X
```

The query states `'less than 1% fat'`, but we actually get more than we wanted:

```
less than 1% fat
less than 1% of doctors recommend this - it's full of fat!
```

To get the required behaviour, I change `@query` to `'less than 1[%] fat'` - then only the first result is returned.

Is there a standard way to prepare strings for clauses which use `LIKE`s, or do I have to roll my own?

Comment: @Oded - User enters 'less than 1% fat', and only gets the result that reads 'less than 1% fat'. i.e. the percentage the user enters is treated as a literal.

Comment: How are you calling the query?

Comment: If you are always searching with a leading wildcard you can use `WHERE CHARINDEX(@query,A) > 0` as characters such as `%` have no special significance to `charindex`. However this will be less efficient if there are no leading wildcards (`LIKE` without a leading wilcard is sargable)

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with injection, perhaps you should change the title. Besides, if you want to use a wildcard as a literal, you have to escape it. What kind of "preparation" are you asking about?

Comment: @Oded - `@query` is a parameter on a stored procedure which gets called from .NET code. The stored procedure glues the '%' chars on either side for the `LIKE`, just as in the example.

Comment: @panagiotis - The OP is asking if there is any built in function to escape the string so that characters such as `%`,`_`,`]`,`[` are treated as literals not pattern syntax or whether they have to roll their own.

Comment: So, you _are_ using a parametrized query.

Comment: @Panagiotis - I chose 'injection' because the user can put characters with special meaning into the query. However, I suppose the word injection could be misleading, especially if people think 'SQL injection' which this is not.

Comment: @Oded - yes, as @Panagiotis pointed out, the word 'injection' might be misleading in the title. If you agree I'll change it.

Comment: I do agree. You are looking for escaping special characters (though the question _is_ related to SQL Injection).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using LIKE you can use free-text search and the [CONTAINS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) or [FREETEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176078.aspx) predicates. LIKE with a leading wildcard ignores indexes and results in a full table scan while the full-text searches use existing free-text indexes to speed up the search. You will have to configure [free text indexing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142497.aspx) before you can use it.

If you want to stick with LIKE the best solution would be to escape the string in your client code. T-SQL provides very limited string manipulation functionality and the [REPLACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) function doesn't even accept wildcards. You would have to nest multiple REPLACE statements to account for all wildcards used by LIKE.

You can combine that with the ESCAPE clause and use a rare character like §, ¶ or ¤ as an escape character if your search string may contain the [ or ] characters.

Comment: +1 - Cool, sounds like what I could be after. I think we could really benefit from free text indexing anyway. Would be good to know another way  without fti though.

Comment: The easiest way would be to escape all wildcards in your client code using the ESCAPE close with a character like ¤ . You could do it with T-SQL's REPLACE but it's a very limited function

Comment: I think I'll opt for enclosing special characters with brackets e.g. `[%]` - according to msdn (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx), that even works for `[[]`. I think I've got a lot of tests to write to make sure this works.

Comment: But good point about §, ¶ or ¤ - I think my conscience would remain pretty clean if I excluded one of those from user input.

Answer (score 6):

SQL Server allows you to specify an [escape character](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx), then you can just escape the query string before using it.

Sample from the MSDN page I linked:

```
SELECT c1 
FROM mytbl2
WHERE c1 LIKE '%10-15!% off%' ESCAPE '!';
```

Comment: +1: Fair option - so this would involve some processing of my own? E.g. `"%" + query.Replace("%", "!%") + "%";`?

Comment: Yes, you'd need to add your escape character before all characters that you want to replace (likely all of these: `%_[]^` - see the posted link for details).

Comment: yep, I think `%`, `_` and `[` are enough reading the spec. `^` is only valid inside `[]` and `]` only means something after a `[`. If all `[`s are escaped then we'll never need to escape `]` and `^`. That's what I've implemented anyway.